# C# object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

what i did wrong here? Anyone can sugest a fix or give me a insight? Thanks :) The error is on last **if** statament.

Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private static string smethod_2(object object_0)
    {
        string text = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < object_0.Length; i++)
        {
            byte b = object_0[i];
            int num = (int)b;
            int num2 = num & 15;
            int num3 = num >> 4 & 15;
            if (num3 > 9)
            {
                text += ((char)(num3 - 10 + 65)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                text += num3.ToString();
            }
            if (num2 > 9)
            {
                text += ((char)(num2 - 10 + 65)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                text += num2.ToString();
            }
            if (i + 1 != object_0.Length && (i + 1) % 2 == 0)
            {
                text += "-"();
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: `object_0` is of type `object` which does not have a `Length` property.  What are you expecting this to do?

Answer (score 3):

object_0 is an object, but you're using it like an array. Looking at the rest of the code, your method signature should look like this:

```
private static string smethod_2(byte[] object_0)
```

Additionally, your line:

```
text += "-"();
```

should look like this:

```
text += "-";
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, i really apreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting an error on every access to `object_0` members, because your code is expecting `object_0` to be declared as a `byte[]` array but you have declared it as an `object` instead, which does not have `Length` or `[]` members.